# How to use a struct pointer in a map?

Tags: c++

I want to use std::map to store pointers to a struct by using two ints as the key lookup, e.g.:

```
std::map<int, int, my_struct*> my_map;
```

Ideally I would like to write code similar to:

```
struct my_struct* test1 = get_struct_ptr();
my_map[1, 5] = test1;
```

Currently I get an error for the my_map definition:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/map:524:17:
error: called object type 'my_struct *' is not a function or function pointer
```

Is there a way to do this with std::map or is there another type that can handle this requirement?

Comment: Is sorting a requirement for you? Because I guess you could use a nested `std::map` inside another.

Comment: You can have two `int` keys like that.

Comment: Do something like `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, my_struct*> my_map;`...

Comment: Problem solving hint: if you think the problem is the pointer to a struct, try with an int instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is always from one type to another.  You can create a type to store two `int`s for keys using [`std::pair<int, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair), so:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>,  my_struct*> my_map;
my_map[{1, 5}] = test1;
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`std::tuple<int, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), a [`std::array<int, 2>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), or a [`struct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) with two `int` data members (but then you'd have to "teach" the `map` how to compare such structs by withing your own `operator<`; lots of existing questions & answers go into detail about how to do this).

Comment: You don't need `opeartor<` for `std::tuple` nor `std::array`. STL provides it.

Comment: @Zereges: yes - I'd hoped that was clear by my phrasing, but evidently not.  Thanks for the comment.  Cheers.